# Convert background position % to letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to get the background position in letter.

My css code

```css
body {
    background-position: center center;
}
```

I tried this

```
$(document).ready (function () {
   alert($("body").css("background-position"));
});
```

I get the following 50% 50% .
I would like to display the following result .

Comment: Try with vanilla javascript `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundPosition`

Comment: @nicowernli Thank you for the answer, but it does not work I get the following result 50% 50%;
I would like to have a result as center center;